# How does one use (specically the wiring) the OV7670 camera with the Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, wires

If one could tell me where each of the pins on the back of the camera go to, that would be great. if someone added the code also that would be awesome.

Comment: Due to the extreme RAM limitations, "Arduino Uno" and "Camera" are words that generally do not belong in the same sentence, as only in very select applications can you accomplish something useful, and then rarely in a cost effective fashion.

Comment: Im using this type of camera. http://bit.ly/1yZEEAZ

Comment: As Chris Stratton already replied, SRAM is an issue. You can add easily 128KB for 3 euro. Normally a camera needs more (in GBs) and this might be tricky, you have to get into SMD and/or costly RAM (since cheap DRAM is a no go for Arduino). 

However, you probably also will get into problems with the 16 MHz processor which is probably too slow to handle all the data in time.

Maybe an Arduino Due could be better, but I think you have to go to Raspberry or equal/more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect A4 and A5 via pullup register to 3V and to I2C interface on Arduino Uno.
And you need to connect A7 to XCLK signal via 2 registers.

You can find schema and code in my blog: [How to connect Arduino Uno and OV7670](http://privateblog.info/arduino-uno-i-kamera-ov7670-primer-ispolzovaniya/)